Avast shows 6 launchers in the startup
Avast Antivirus on a freshly-built Windows PC shows one launcher in the startup (Task Manager > Startup Programs).
But on my older laptop, it shows 6 launchers in the startup – see image attached. Does anybody know why my account has six launchers instead of 1 and how to fix it?
What I mean is that if I log in as another standard user, e.g.: "User2", that user only has one startup launcher. I checked Autoruns, and there is only one entry, which  standard users get. But not my main standard user account.


It only has one. The other six are the processes started by that.

why do you need to fix it?
